# iOS Data passed along from NSDictionary is (null) - JSON source

Tags: ios, objective-c, json, nsdictionary, segue

Alright, so I am segue'ing from my `CatViewController` -> `TopicViewController` using a push segue and I have JSON data being pulled into a dictionary in CVC, and being printed out in a `UITableView`. Once the user selects a row, it is supposed to pull the `categoryID` from the selected `NSDictionary` Object and populate the next view with a different set of JSON data, where the `replyID == categoryID`.

Obviously that isn't the case, and when I print out my `passedData` `NSString`, it shows null.

I thought I was building the `NSDictionary` correctly and then getting the right info but it just doesn't seem to be doing what I want it to do.

**CatViewController.m**

```
- (void) retrieveData;
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:getDataURL];
    NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

    NSLog(@"%@", url);

    jsonArray2 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];

    NSError *error;
    dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    for (catDict in dict) {
        catID = catDict[@"categoryID"];
        NSString *catDesc = catDict[@"categoryDesc"];
        NSString *catName = catDict[@"categoryName"];
        NSLog(catID);
    }

    categoryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray2.count; i++)
    {
        NSString *cID = [[jsonArray2 objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"categoryID"];
        NSString *cDesc = [[jsonArray2 objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"categoryDesc"];
        NSString *cName = [[jsonArray2 objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"categoryName"];

        [categoryArray addObject:[[Categories alloc]initWidthCategoryDesc:cDesc andcategoryName:cName andcategoryID:cID]];
    }

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

---

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"catToTopic"]) {
        TopicViewController *tVC = (TopicViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];

        tVC.passedData = [[[categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"categoryID"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    }
}
```

**TopicViewController.m**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    //test to see what gets passed along
    NSLog(@"%@", passedData);

    self.title = @"Test replies";

    [self retrieveData];

    UITableViewController *tvController = [[UITableViewController alloc] init];
    tvController.tableView = self.tableView;

    self.refreshControl = [[UIRefreshControl alloc] init];
    [self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(updateTable:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    tvController.refreshControl = self.refreshControl;
}
```

---

**Output**

```
2015-03-12 02:29:25.036 Aviato[3081:195303] Login SUCCESS
2015-03-12 02:29:25.314 Aviato[3081:195303] http://tandemenvoy.michaeldvinci.com/forum/categoriesJSON.php
2015-03-12 02:29:25.315 Aviato[3081:195303] 2
2015-03-12 02:29:25.315 Aviato[3081:195303] 5
2015-03-12 02:29:25.315 Aviato[3081:195303] 6
2015-03-12 02:29:25.316 Aviato[3081:195303] 7
2015-03-12 02:29:25.316 Aviato[3081:195303] 8
2015-03-12 02:29:25.316 Aviato[3081:195303] 9
2015-03-12 02:29:25.316 Aviato[3081:195303] 10
2015-03-12 02:29:25.316 Aviato[3081:195303] 11
2015-03-12 02:29:25.317 Aviato[3081:195303] 12
2015-03-12 02:29:25.317 Aviato[3081:195303] 13
2015-03-12 02:29:25.317 Aviato[3081:195303] 14
2015-03-12 02:29:25.317 Aviato[3081:195303] 15
2015-03-12 02:29:27.052 Aviato[3081:195303] (null)
2015-03-12 02:29:27.328 Aviato[3081:195303] http://tandemenvoy.michaeldvinci.com/forum/repliesJSON.php
```

Comment: What is the value of indexpath.section and indexpath.row ?
Try to pass it with a hard code value\

Comment: Can you post the jsonArray2 please?

Comment: 2015-03-12 03:13:42.600 Aviato[3170:202855] (
        {
        categoryDesc = "Attempt at an actual catefory";
        categoryID = 2;
        categoryName = TestCat;
    },
        {
        categoryDesc = "kjnk,m";
        categoryID = 5;
        categoryName = qwert;
    },
        {
        categoryDesc = hi;
        categoryID = 6;
        categoryName = trewq;
    },
        {
        categoryDesc = m;
        categoryID = 7;
        categoryName = retrievethis;
    },
        {
        categoryDesc = j;
        categoryID = 8;
        categoryName = qwqwqw;
    }
**(was too long)**

Answer (score 0):

```
tVC.passedData =[categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].catID;
```

pass this value only.

Comment: sorry! passedData was printed out as: '2015-03-12 03:21:01.225 Aviato[3190:204280] category ID value = <Categories: 0x174234560>'

Comment: [categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row].catID

Just use this

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSString *categoryIDClicked = [categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog("category ID value = %@", categoryIDClicked);
}
```

If you want to use categoryIDClicked to another class you must take global variable then you can use any where through out the project.

Comment: 2015-03-12 03:04:25.578 Aviato[3131:200764] category ID value = <Categories: 0x1744207a0>
2015-03-12 03:04:25.622 Aviato[3131:200764] (null)

so it looks like it's just getting the pointer to it, so I'm not getting the right stuff - even if my UITableView is populating correctly??

Comment: first you should print array. Check whether It should contains values or not

Comment: **array:**  03:13:42.600 Aviato[3170:202855] (
        {
        categoryDesc = "Attempt at an actual catefory";
        categoryID = 2;
        categoryName = TestCat;
    },
        {
        categoryDesc = "kjnk,m";
        categoryID = 5;
        categoryName = qwert;
    },
        {
        categoryDesc = hi;
        categoryID = 6;
        categoryName = trewq;
    },
        {
        categoryDesc = m;
        categoryID = 7;
        categoryName = retrievethis;
    },
        {
        categoryDesc = j;
        categoryID = 8;
        categoryName = qwqwqw;
    }
**(was too long)**

Comment: I'm looking to pass categoryID over to my TopicViewController, so I can use a second .JSON and populate TPC with (replyTopic == categoryID)

Comment: in JSON there is no array along with the category ID its an array with the dictionary so you just need to pass 
[[categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"categoryID"];

Comment: so set | tVC.passedData = [[categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"categoryID"]; | ---?

Comment: categoryID values must be stored in categoryArray

Answer (score 0):

Try(assuming that you try to pass categoryId)

```
Categories* cat = [categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    tVC.passedData = cat.categoryID ;
```

instead

```
tVC.passedData = [[[categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] valueForKey:@"categoryID"] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```